# How to get common validation error message for array field

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I need to validate a request with image and tags. How to return a common validation error message for tags.

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'image' => 'required|image,
    'tags.*' => 'string'
]);
```

Currecnt message is.

```
{
    "image": [
        "The image field is required."
    ],
    "tags.0": [
        "The tags.0 must be a string."
    ],
    "tags.1": [
        "The tags.1 must be a string."
    ]
}
```

Expected message is.

```
{
    "image": [
        "The image field is required."
    ],
    "tags": [
        "The tags must be a string."
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this,

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'image' => 'required|image,
    'tags.*' => 'string'
],$messages = [
    'tags.*' => 'The tags must be a string.'
]);
```

I'm not quit sure but this might work for you.

Comment: The message changed. but it comes on multiple array index. "tags.0": [
        "The tags must be a string."
    ],
    "tags.1": [
        "The tags must be a string."
    ]

Comment: @noufalcep This is because you have multiple incorrect fields of array input field

Comment: Yes. I need a single error message for the multiple inputs.

Comment: @noufalcep you can do it in in view.  just take single message from array of message but it's not a good way

Comment: I can't do it in view. I will find another solution.

Comment: @noufalcep best of luck !

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try with similar below example:

```
public function messages()
        {
            $messages = [];
            foreach ($this->request->get('tags') as $key => $val) {
                $messages['tags.' . $key . '.string'] = 'The tags must be a string.'
            }
            return $messages;
        }
```

Hope this work for you !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can add messages with a `*` to your translation file, [as documented](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#validating-arrays).

```
'custom' => [
    'tags.*' => [
        'string' => 'The tags must be a string.',
    ]
],
```

Comment: The message changed. but it comes on multiple array index. "tags.0": [ "The tags must be a string." ], "tags.1": [ "The tags must be a string." ]